# Is there a speed difference between an if check and a while check

Tags: c++, performance, if-statement, while-loop

I am solving a question where theres a main while loop with condition being `int i =0; while(i<vector.size())` and inside this while loop I have another while loop that increases i if current element in the index is odd. Such as `while(i<vector.size()&&vector[i]%2!=0 )i++;`. My question is if i replaced the second while loop with and if statement, would my performance be different? which would be faster and why? I know Big O complexity would be O(N) in both cases but I am talking about real world speed. I am using c++ if it matters. Does the compiler make optimizations for the while loop/ is there more checks to do in an if statement and so on? This is just a question out of curiosity.

```
int i=0;
vector<int> temp(1000,1);
while(i<temp.size())
{
   while(i<temp.size()&&temp[i]%2!=0)
  {
    i++;
  }
}
```

or

```
int i=0;
vector<int> temp(1000,1);
while(i<temp.size())
{
   if(i<temp.size()&&temp[i]%2!=0)
  {
    i++;
  }
}
```

Comment: What is preventing you from testing this yourself?

Comment: testing it myself would just show me if  one is faster on my own compiler. But im asking in theoretical sense.

Comment: It depends on compiler and optimization level. A compiler could replace the whole code with `int i=1000` in both cases. You can use https://godbolt.org/ to test many different compilers

Comment: What's `vector`?

Comment: The two snippets are not identical, so a performance comparison is meaningless. ``temp[i]%2` does not check whether `i` is odd, but whether `temp[i]` is.

Comment: Its c++ array container @SombreroChicken

Comment: No. I meant `vector` in your code. There's no variable named `vector`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's based on a trivial misunderstanding.

Comment: My goal was never to check whether if i was odd @MSalters

Comment: @SombreroChicken sorry i just realized that, fixed it now.

Comment: You can simplify that to `while (i < temp.size() && temp[i] % 2 != 0) i++;`, but the time complexity of a loop that doesn't terminate at all in the worst case is very far from linear.

Comment: single `if` is theoretically O(1), while `while` is O(N), so if you look only on the one 
inner line of your example, the `if` is "better", but also producing completely different result. If you take into account also the outer loop, the result of both will be identical, and in big-O notation both will require the same amount of operations and a good optimizing compiler will highly likely produce identical machine code for both. But even if you would keep adding complexity to the example, in terms of big-O, as long as both variants are looking for first even value in linear way = same O(N).

Comment: You could print the assembly language listing and compare the two.  Do this for all optimization settings with your compiler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From a performance point of view, the difference is negligible. And any decent compiler will transform both snippets of your code to (nearly) identical assembly depending on your optimization settings.

From a design point of view, it makes no sense to have two loops or a nested loop and an if inside loop in the first place. As you could easily rewrite your condition in just one loop.

When it comes to performance comparison questions the first thing to do is benchmark the code yourself. [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/) is a great website to check the produced assembly differences for different codes and compilers.

Really though, unless you're working with very very very specific software and hardware that can not afford to delay a few clock cycles then this kind of optimization is premature. Unless, you know your platform and code very well the compiler will outsmart you in generating fast assembly. Just focus on getting correct and readable code.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your outer while() loop becomes infinite if any of the element is even (`i` will not be incremented). What is the performance of an infinite loop?